# Facebook FQL query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the facebook share count, link count and comments count for a page in my site. I am trying to use FQL for that. Here is my code:

```
<?php   
         $query = "select comment_count, share_count, like_count from link_stat 
         where url=<my_url_of_page>";  
         //My FQL Query

         $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=".$query;
         $fbData = file_get_contents($url);
         echo $fbData;    
?>
```

When I run the same query in graph explorer it is giving correct results. When as when I am calling it from my machine, it is showing blank page.

Please suggest am I doing something wrong here.

-- Thanks for your time.

Comment: doesn't it need an access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `login as an app` before you can use the `link stat` table.

Follow the steps in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/) to login as an app.